# Python: mutable list and del keyword

Tags: python

Here an example:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = l1

l1.append(4)
l2.append(5)

print(l1) # result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l2) # result: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Okey, it is because that list are mutable.

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = l1

l1.append(4)
l2.append(5)

del l2

print(l1) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(l2) #  NameError: name 'l2' is not defined
```

Why is l1 not deleted?

Comment: Because `l2` and `l1` are references to same list. `del l2` deletes reference variable, not list. You can use `del l2[:]` though or `l2.clear()`.

Comment: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 1):

I agree the answer of Olvin Roght.

Just add some details, the `del` keyword unbinds the name of the variable with any referenced memory block.

*Deletion of a name removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace, depending on whether the name occurs in a global statement in the same code block. If the name is unbound, a NameError exception will be raised.*

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement

So obviously, if you only unbind the `l2` variable, `l1` is still avalaible.

Comment: "referenced memory block"->"object". This is python, it is rarely useful to think in terms of "memory blocks"